# How to put a logo without border in the top left corner in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website with a logo in the top left corner. 
My problem is that when I try to add the logo and move it to the left top corner, I have a margin that I can not delete. I tried the following:

In HTML File:

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="pic/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo" />
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.logo {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

However it still has some margin.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Helps to see where that margin is.

Answer (score 0):

That could be due to browsers' default style. You can reset it in css like:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You'll have to manually define `margin` and `padding` for all the elements that need it, however.